# python one line for loop over a function returning a tuple

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tuples, line

I've tried searching quite a lot on this one, but being relatively new to python I feel I am missing the required terminology to find what I'm looking for.

I have a function:

```
def my_function(x,y):
    # code...
    return(a,b,c)
```

Where `x` and `y` are `numpy` arrays of length 2000 and the return values are integers. I'm looking for a shorthand (one-liner) to loop over this function as such:

```
Output = [my_function(X[i],Y[i]) for i in range(len(Y))]
```

Where `X` and `Y` are of the shape (135,2000). However, after running this I am currently having to do the following to separate out 'Output' into three `numpy` arrays.

```
Output = np.asarray(Output)
a = Output.T[0]
b = Output.T[1]
c = Output.T[2]
```

Which I feel isn't the best practice. I have tried:

```
(a,b,c) = [my_function(X[i],Y[i]) for i in range(len(Y))]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know a quick way around my problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you under the assumption that a one-liner will be "better" (and by "better" I mean more readable) than a ""multi-liner""? Don't get me wrong, I'm usually up for one-liners, but not at the cost of readability.

Comment: More just out of interest I guess, I’m coding on an individual project so felt it was a good opportunity to explore other styles.

Answer (score 0):

`my_function(X[i], Y[i]) for i in range(len(Y))`

On the verge of crossing the "opinion-based" border, `...Y[i]... for i in range(len(Y))` is usually a big no-no in Python. It is even a bigger no-no when working with `numpy` arrays. One of the advantages of working with `numpy` is the 'vectorization' that it provides, and thus pushing the `for` loop down to the C level rather than the (slower) Python level.

So, if you rewrite `my_function` so it can handle the arrays in a vectorized fashion using the multiple tools and methods that `numpy` provides, you may not even need that "one-liner" you are looking for.

Comment: Ah ok! That sounds like exactly what I should be looking into then!